# how to understand the definition of continuity in analysis?

Tags: analysis, continuity, definition, intuition

[image]

Please have a look at the picture above.
This is about the continuity in analysis.
I don't really understand how to utilize this definition?

It says that is statement is equivalent to f is continuous at x.
How to relate it to neighbourbood and open ball?
Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Finally a text that uses all the quantifiers.

Answer (score 1):

The italicized statement is a definition of "$f$ is continuous at $x$" where $f$ is a function from a metric space $X$ to a metric space $Y$.  Any neighbourhood of $f(x)$ in $Y$ contains an open ball $B_\epsilon(f(x)) = \{y: d_Y(y,f(x))<\epsilon\}$.  The statement says that for every such neighbourhood of $f(x)$ 
there is an open ball $B_\delta(x) = \{z: d_X(z,x) < \delta\}$ that $f$ maps into the neighbourhood.

Answer (score -3):

**Hint:**

This definition simply states that $f$ is continuos at $x$ iff $$\lim_{z\rightarrow x}\, f(z) = f(x)$$

It can be proved that it is equivalent to the topological definition of coninuity *i.e.* $f$ is continuous iff the image of an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ through $f$ is an open subset of the set $\mathrm{Range}(f)$.

An open ball is a particular kind of neighbourbood, since $\forall r >0$, defining $B(x,r)$ you can always find an open ball, like $B(x,r/2)$ which is an open set completely inside $B(x,r)$.

Comment: No: the image of an open set under a continuous map is **not** necessarily open in the range.